# Drupal 7 (VERY) Custom Preview

Tags: json, drupal, service, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a drupal site that is being used strictly as a CMS that produces JSON feeds using services and services_views, which are consumed by a separate site.  What I would like to do (and I have a working proof of concept of this) is allow for a "live preview" on the real site, by intercepting the node form preview / submit, encoding the node as JSON, and loading a special page on the live site that consumes that JSON and displays the page accordingly.

The problem with this JSONized node is, it's different from the JSON being produced by my view (using services_views).  My end goal is to produce JSON that is identical for both previewed and non-previewed objects, without having to maintain separate output methods (I could easily hand-customize the json but then when my view for the public api changes I have to make the same changes to the preview json.  Trying to avoid this).

I'm looking for feedback on this approach.  Is what I'm attempting even possible?  The ideas I've been able to come up with so far are:

- being able to (conditionally) drive my view with data from a non-databse source
- sneakily inserting data into the view object during one of the stages of execution? Kludgy but I'm not above that :)
- saving a "clone" node (or revision?) of the node being previewed and let the view use that to display the preview JSON?

Maybe this is the wrong approach altogether and there's something better? (Trying to intercept and format the services output in my module... maybe avoid services_views altogether?)

If anyone can offer some advice, insight or opinions on how to best proceed here, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

in a custom module, you could set up a page that grabs the json output from the view page.

```
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);
```

that way the preview stays bound to the view, even if the view changes.

Comment: Ok, but the view only displays content that's already saved to the node (saved to the db). During a preview I've either got unsaved changes to an existing node, or a new / altogether unsaved node...

Answer (score 0):

First I think it's not an easy task what you are trying to achieve. So before all, good luck.

I think you could intercept the node submission data, then create a node programatically, then render that node, and then export the rendered node to JSON. Inmediately after you get the JSON, delete this node, because the programmatically created node is only for preview.

This task could be more CPU demanding but think that previewing content exactly as the content will look is difficult.

Your rss feeds that your site reads could be filtered with some parameter to avoid programmatically created nodes (prewiew nodes), despite these nodes will be available for a very short time.